# Convert string values in Pandas Dateframe to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error, string-to-datetime

I have a dataframe (data) where one column('BEG_DT') is a string representation of a date in the format of YYYYmmdd (example 19490713 = 1949, July, 13).

```
data[data.columns[0:3]].head()
```

```
    NCDC         BEG_DT      END_DT
1   10000001    19490713    19501115
2   10000001    19590701    19621001
3   10000001    19621001    19630129
4   10000001    19630129    19670125
5   10000001    19670125    19800205
```

```
data.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 277297 entries, 0 to 277296
Data columns (total 32 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------        --------------   ----- 
 0   NCDC          277297 non-null  object
 1   BEG_DT        277297 non-null  object
 2   END_DT        277297 non-null  object
```

```
type(data.iloc[1]['BEG_DT'])
```

```
str
```

I need to convert the BEG_DT column to a datetime column.  When I use the following:

```
pd.to_datetime(data['BEG_DT'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-61a349589cf7> in <module>
----> 1 pd.to_datetime(data['BEG_DT'], format='%Y%m%d')

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

I can recreate the same error with this toy example:

```
ser1 = ['A','B','C']
ser2 = ['19920525', '19430224','19590216']
adf=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','B','C'],'col2':['19920525', '19430224','19590216']})
```

```
adf
```

```
    col1    col2
0   A   19920525
1   B   19430224
2   C   19590216
```

```
adf['Date']=pd.to_datetime(adf['col2'])
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-48d6423da8db> in <module>
----> 1 adf['Date']=pd.to_datetime(adf['col2'])

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

I believe that the syntax is correct according to the Pandas to_datetime documentation, so my understanding of how this works is incorrect.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It works with pandas 1.1.5 and 1.2.4

Comment: @Corralien - Thanks for the feedback.  Tried on another machine and it worked.  Recreated the virtual environment and it worked.  I am using 1.2.4.